# Does SharePoint API offer an endpoint for doing a full text search on the content of the documents?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api

I am using SharePoint as a DMS for my app.
Via the SharePoint API I am uploading, and downloading files, and retrieving folders and files.
I have been using the standard url blueprint:
`https://{{TenantName}}.sharepoint.com/sites/{{SiteName}}/_api/web/...`

I need to add a full text search in the app. I need to be able to send a queryString parameter to the API, and to get returned all files that contain that string. Not in their name, but in their content.

Is that even possible? Could not find it online. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can use the following REST API to search in SharePoint:

```
GET http://{server}/_api/search/query?querytext='sharepoint'
```

I suggest you can refer to this document: [SharePoint Search REST API overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview)

Hope it can help you.